# Session timeout error on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have created a custom button and added it to a console application. What happens is when a particular profile user do not do any activity then after 10 to 15 minutes on clicking the custom button user is redirected to dashboard.Also , when I return to the same page again I got a pop up on button click i.e problem with on click javascript. Invalid _session_ID fault code: invalid session.

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var oppid = '{!Opportunity.Id}'; 
var get = null; 
var cases = null; 
var openCase = null; 
var caseNumber = null; 
var caseId = null; 

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Case__r.Id, Case__r.Status, Case__r.CaseNumber FROM Opportunity WHERE (Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND Case__r.Status != 'Closed')"); 

if(result != null || typeof result != 'undefined') 
{ 
get = result.getArray('records')[0]; 

if( get != null || typeof get != 'undefined') 
{ 
cases = get.getArray('Case__r'); 

if(cases == null || typeof openCase == 'undefined' || cases.length == 0){ 
srcUp('/apex/LogACallVSFPage?opportunitid='+oppid); 
} else if(cases.length > 1){ 
alert('There are multiple open cases on this loan. Please choose a case to log your call on.'); 
} else { 
openCase = cases[0]; 

if(openCase != null || typeof openCase != 'undefined'){ 
caseNumber = openCase.get('CaseNumber'); 
caseId = openCase.get('Id'); 
} else { 
alert('An error occured. Please contact your administrator.'); 
} 

if( (caseNumber != null || caseNumber != 'undefined') && (caseId != null || caseId != 'undefined')){ 

if(confirm('There is an open case on this account. Please Go to Open Case ' + caseNumber + ' to Log the Call.')== true){ 
srcUp('/' + caseId); 
} 
} else { 
alert('An error occured. Please contact your administrator.'); 
} 
} 

} else { 
srcUp('/apex/LogACallVSFPage?opportunitid='+oppid); 
} 

} else { 
alert('An error occured. Please contact your administrator.'); 
}
```

Please help me as I am also debugging the issue. It happens for a particular profile only.

Comment: Does this profile has access to the VisualForce page ?

Answer (score 2):

After

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
```

Add

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
```

This will solve your **session-timeout-error**  issue

Comment: I am just implementing and testing in UAT will update and mark as answer :)

Comment: Its not working . Testing again :(

Comment: @cloudlover are you still facing invalid  session issue.. I believe you are facing other issue not invalid session issue ?

Comment: Hi @ratan the org session timeoutvalue is 12 hr , when user do nothing in console vf page then he get redirected to homepage.For this particular instant VF session in session management is set to 15 minutes. It expire beyond that.Is the issue have any relation , Can we increase the VF session?

Comment: @cloudlover may be you are facing this known issue. check this out https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZO5AAM  Currently salesforce fixing this issue.

Comment: appreciate your answer but there is a different scenario happening. The timeout for a profile is working for a particular VF page in console. The user is redirected to dashboard without any session over popup message. As in usual functionality it needs to logout.